# Location to bookmark mapping

Tags: bookmarks, bookmark+

Is there a function that, for a given location (e.g. the ongoing file/line number) returns an existing bookmark (if any)?

I've looked at the list of functions in bookmark and bookmark+ libraries and could not find one.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you're asking. You can have any number of bookmarks at a given buffer position or file position.

Function `bookmark-get-position` returns the recorded position of a given bookmark. You can filter the bookmarks in the current `bookmark-alist` with a function that tests that position.

With [Bookmark+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus) you also have commands such as `bmkp-bookmarks-lighted-at-point`, which returns a list of the bookmarks highlighted at the cursor position:

> **`bmkp-bookmarks-lighted-at-point`** is an interactive compiled Lisp
> function in `bookmark+-lit.el`.
>
> It is bound to `C-x x =`, `menu-bar file bookmark bookmarks-here bmkp-bookmarks-lighted-at-point`, `menu-bar file bookmark highlight bmkp-bookmarks-lighted-at-point`.
>
> `(bmkp-bookmarks-lighted-at-point &optional POSITION FULLP MSGP)`
>
> **Return a list of the bookmarks highlighted at point.**
>
> Include only those in the current bookmark list (`bookmark-alist`).
>
> - With no prefix arg, return the bookmark names.
> - With a prefix arg, return the full bookmark data.
>
> Interactively, display the info.
>
> Non-interactively:
>
> - Use the bookmarks at optional arg `POSITION` (default: point).
> - Optional arg `FULLP` means return full bookmark data.
> - Optional arg `MSGP` means display the info.

And function `bmkp-choose-bookmark-lighted-at-point`:

> **`bmkp-choose-bookmark-lighted-at-point`** is a compiled Lisp function in
> `bookmark+-lit.el`.
>
> `(bmkp-choose-bookmark-lighted-at-point &optional POSITION NOERRORP)`
>
> **Return the name of a bookmark lighted at `POSITION` (default: point).**
>
> If there is more than one such, prompt user to choose one.
>
> Optional arg `POSITION` is a buffer position to use instead of point.
>
> Raise an error if there is no highlighted bookmark present, unless
> optional arg `NOERRORP` is non-`nil`, in which case return `nil`.